# elasticsearch python api overwrites the existing field

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch Python API, I found if the `_id` is same the old data would be overwritten. e.g. I had `name="Tom"`, right now I index the same `_id` with field `age=30`. I found the `name="Tom"` was removed after the reindex. The right result I hope `age=30` only appended to the existing index. Should I tune any parameters please?

I'm using the following code:

```python
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch("http://10.0.0.1:9200")
res = es.index(index="panavstream", doc_type='panav', id="123", body=doc)
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`update` function with `script` body can append a field in data. [elasticsearch-py update](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.update)

the sample:

```
doc = {
  'script' : 'ctx._source.age = 30'
}
es.update(index="panavstream", doc_type='panav', id="123", body=doc)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not familiar with ES script, could you please give me a reference of indexing scripts.